# Will this Reactive Extensions code leak memory?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have written some code which turns the `FileSystemWatcher`'s `Changed` event in to an observable sequence.

My goal is two split all file system changes in to separate streams and throttling them.

For example if I have 10 different files which change 3 times in half a second, I'll only get a notifcation once for each file.

What concerns me though is the `GroupBy()` operator. For this to work, (I assume) it would need to keep building up the group over time and consuming small amounts of memory.

Will this cause a "leak" and if so, how can I prevent it?

```
FileSystemWatcher _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher("d:\\") {
    EnableRaisingEvents = true,
    NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Size
};

void Main()
{
    var fileSystemEventStream = 
        Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>
            (
                _ => _watcher.Changed += _, 
                _ => _watcher.Changed -= _
            )
            .ObserveOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance)
            .SubscribeOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance)
            .GroupBy(ep => ep.EventArgs.FullPath, ep => ep.EventArgs.FullPath)
            ;

    var res = 
        from fileGroup in fileSystemEventStream
        from file in fileGroup.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        select file;

    res.Subscribe(
        ReceiveFsFullPath, 
        exception => {
            Console.WriteLine ("Something went wrong - " + exception.Message + " " + exception.StackTrace);
        });

    Console.Read();
}

void ReceiveFsFullPath(string s){
    Console.WriteLine ("Received file system event on thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: If you believe in c# garnage collector, and you shouldn't, there is no leak

Comment: But the group is holding a reference the same file over time. I understand C# is garbage collected, but it doesn't mean memory leaks don't happen.

Comment: Have you tried attaching a profiler such as [SciTech's Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/) to see if you are leaking?

Comment: Good point,  I'll give that a go. I'd still like to know how to prevent it.

Comment: @StefanoFalasca how am I supposed to write C# code when I can't rely on it collecting garbage? It's not like I can manually free anything. (that obviously doesn't mean that any construct is guaranteed to be leak free, when you keep references to collections that keep accumulating references to new objects)

Comment: This would not be a memory leak. Just a probably bad design requiring an unreasonabke amount of memory. You have a memory leak when a hunk of memory which has been made available for you does not get available for other uses when you are no longer able to use it (because you lost all references to it).

Comment: @martijn And, you actually cannot rely on the garbage collector, yet you (and a lot more people) keep using it. I've heard people saying that since c# is garbage collected, it's ok for the memory consumpion of their application to grow undefinitely when the application is idle. They keep using it, even if the application crashes after 20 minute or so of being idle.

Comment: @StefanoFalasca so... how do you reclaim heap memory if not relying on the garbage collector?

Comment: @martijn you do not. What I am saying is simply that c# is an unreliable language, as far as I know. It might well be that this is not true, but I have seen lots of c# projects accumulating memory while idle and I have seen too much microsoft code to be assuming that it might work.

Comment: @martijn you do not. What I am saying is simply that c# is an unreliable language, as far as I know. It might well be that this is not true, but I have seen lots of c# projects accumulating memory while idle and I have seen too much microsoft code to be assuming that it might work.

Comment: @StefanoFalasca ah, I didn't know that. In what situations does the .NET GC not relaim dead objects? It's rather important to me to know because I do work a lot in C#. Also, do the Mono GC's have the same problems? Or is this better for a seperate question?

Comment: I think the general mis-understanding of .NET GC is off topic. There are lots of overly complicated blogs and pages on this topic, but this may be a good start for those in this converstation http://www.kevinberridge.com/2007/04/memory-leaks-and-garbage-collection.html

Comment: @Martijn - don't let Stefano's second-hand fear of garbage collected languages dissuade you from using C# or any other GC'd language.  They are no more "unreliable" than any of the other languages.  It is the code written by developers that is "unreliable".  C# protects you from many common errors that you might do in a language like C#, but it doesn't protect you from everything.  No matter what language you use, you need to understand the contracts it provides.  The OP's question and Lee Campbell's link are a good example of how you can still get into trouble with a GC'ed language.

Comment: @Martijn I strongly agree with Brandon. The problem is often with what the programmer thinks the language/runtime to guarantee. My secobd hand experience, as Brandon puts it :), can be that of a situation where there is no bug in the GC, yet memory leaks are happening because programmers think c# is going to fix everything for them. My personal opinion is that a microsoft language cannot be trusted (beware, this is not because I don't like the company or because I am advocating some cause, I just had plenty of examples of bad coding and bad software/managerial choices from them).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, for each new key, GroupBy creates a Subject, and maintains a dictionary of these subjects.  And you are subscribing to each of these.  So that is a small chunk of memory that will grow over time without anyway to release the old entries.  What you really need is for the key to be removed when the throttle timer expires.  I cannot think of a way to do this with the builtin operators.  So you need a custom operator.  Here's a stab at one.

```
public IObservable<T> ThrottleDistinct<T>(this IObservable<T> source, TimeSpan delay)
{
    return Observable.Create(observer =>
    {
        var notifications = new Subject<IObservable<T>>();
        var subscription = notifications.Merge().Subscribe(observer);
        var d = new Dictionary<T, IObserver<T>>();
        var gate = new object();
        var sourceSubscription = new SingleAssignmentDisposable();
        var subscriptions = new CompositeDisposable(subscription, sourceSubscription);
        sourceSubscription.Disposable = source.Subscribe(value =>
        {
           IObserver<T> entry;
           lock(gate)
           {
             if (d.TryGetValue(value, out entry))
             {
               entry.OnNext(value);
             }
             else
             {
               var s = new Subject<T>();
               var o = s.Throttle(delay).FirstAsync().Do(() =>
               {
                 lock(gate)
                 {
                   d.Remove(value);
                 }
               });
               notifications.OnNext(o);
               d.Add(value, s);
               s.OnNext(value);
             }
          }
        }, observer.OnError, notifications.OnCompleted);

        return subscriptions;
    });
}

...
Observable.FromEventPattern(...)
    .Select(e => e.EventArgs.FullPath)
    .ThrottleDistinct(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .Subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Appreciate the time you spent in writing your answer. I saw this thread on the MSDN forums. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/53a66a85-4ab3-4fe9-96c6-8b72cc034d0e/groupbyuntil-usage Could having an expiring group with a group size maximum of one be the answer? I'd like to avoid writing code with locks if there's a built in mechanism :)

Comment: Yes.  I didn't know about GroupByUntil!  It's API is a little awkward but this should work: `filenames.GroupByUntil(f=>f, g=>g.Throttle(delay)).SelectMany(g => g.LastAsync());

Answer (score 1):

As per Brandon's reply, the subjects will grow and have no way of being reclaimed*. My main concern with leaking memory here is that you don't capture the subscription! i.e.

```
res.Subscribe(...
```

must be replaced with

```
subscription = res.Subscribe(...
```

if you don't capture the subscription, you can never dispose of the subscription, thus you never release the event handlers, thus you have "leaked memory". Obviously this is no use if you dont somewhere actually dispose of the subscription.

*Well, if they completed then they would be auto disposed, so that would work. You could look to complete a sequence when a FileDeleted event came through?

Comment: I am capturing the subscription, I just didn't add that bit of code in. I've basically taken the query out of our code base and made it LINQPad friendly that's all. Even so, if this query runs for the life of the application and the subscription doesn't end then we have a "leak" :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. GroupByUntil seems to be what you are looking for (even though you have still yet to explain under what conditions you want to release the sequences)

Comment: By definition of the stated problem you can release the sequence whenever it is idle longer than the throttle period.  There is no "visible" difference in the output sequence between the original version of the code and the version using `GroupByUntil`, except the latter will release resources when idle.